# Explanation of CDATA?

Tags: xml, web-services, cdata

I have noticed that if I send decoded XML to an endpoint, it fails with a bad request error, but if I wrap the request in CDATA or encode the characters, it runs fine, so my two questions are:

Why do I need to use CDATA or encode the characters?

What is it about the web service that makes me have to do this?

What is the difference between wrapping the message in CDATA and encoding the characters?

If CDATA is ignored by the parser, doesn't that mean the message your are trying to send won't be processed?

My webservice has web method called Process, but the message that is trying to be sent is MessageB, so do I need to wrap the contents of MessageB in CDATA because the XML Parser won't understand it?

If my web-service contained a web-method called MessageB, would it still be required to be wrapped in CDATA or escaped?  My case is that I don't have a web-method MessageB, but something called Process which listens for the MessageB request through a switch statement.  I am thinking because I don't have MessageB defined as a web-method, that is the reason why I have to wrap it in CDATA or escape it, but I believe my thinking is wrong?

Comment: A simple [google search](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) can answer all of these questions.

Comment: You need to learn how XML works.

Comment: @asawyer - That is actually where I originally read about it, but I was still confused.

Comment: @SLaks - Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wrap or encode the data, it will become part of the main XML document. When the web service tries to parse the document, it will find elements that it can't map to what it expects, and spits it out.

This is not specific to web services, but applies anytime you want to use XML code as a value inside an XML document.

There is little practical difference between using CDATA and encoding the characters. It's just two different ways of embedding special characters in a value in an XML document.

Comment: When you say it can't find elements that it can't map to, are you also referring to a web method that it can't find

Comment: @Xaisoft: No, I mean that the web service expects an element with just a text value in it, and it finds instead a bunch of other elements in it. By encoding the characters it will be seen as a text value, not as elements.

Comment: OK, I edited my post to indicate that I have one web method in my web-service, I am assuming that if any other message is sent, that is why I need to wrap the request in CDATA, correct?

Comment: @Xaisoft: It doesn't matter what the value is, the web service framework isn't supposed to try to understand the data at all. If you don't encode the value, the framework will be confused by it, as it looks like something that it should try to understand.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have seen some situations where I send an xml message to and endpoint that is decoded, but does this mean that behind the scenes it is being encoded anyways?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Xaisoft: That depends on how you call the web service. If you for example add a web reference in a Visual Studio project, it will create a class that contains method that you use to call the web service, and the methods will automatically encode all data that you send.

Answer (score 1):

Characters like `&` and `<` are *not allowed* to appear in XML.

The XML standard requires that they either bee escaped with XML entities or that they be wrapped in `<![CDATA[` blocks, which tells XML parses to treat the entire block as plain text.

You should be using an XML library on your end that takes care of this for you; you should never build XML by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Some characters have special meaning in XML. For example, `<` means "Start of tag" and `&` means "Start of character reference".

CDATA markers indicate that some content is plain text and not markup, so `<` means "A less than sign" and `&` means "An ampersand".

Comment: Why would some web services require plain text?

Comment: Because whomever designed it, designed it that way. I wouldn't like to speculate on why someone built an unspecified service in a particular (vaguely specified) way.

Comment: When I generate the  message through soap-ui from the wsdl, I get a structure similar to the following <Request>?</Request>.  Does <Request> pertain to my Process web method and anything in between request needs to be wrapped in CDATA or escaped?

Answer (score 0):

If you send the message `<a><b/></a>` to someone, that's different from the message `<a><[CDATA[<b/>]]></a>`. Neither is right or wrong, but one might be what the recipient expects while the other is not. It's up to the consumer of the XML to say what kind of messages it understands. There's nothing intrinsic about web services that says anything has to be in CDATA, it's just that this particular web service appears to have been designed this way.

Comment: Michael, when you say designed this way, what exactly do you mean, do you have an example of a web service that would require CDATA blocks?